# Save and load the value of radio buttons doesn't work c#

Tags: c#, .net, radio-button

I'm coding a software in C# in which I use regedit to store some preference of the user. One of the preference is: which radio button is checked. That's how it looks:

```
String readPreference = (String)Registry.GetValue(RegLocation, "Preference", "true;false");
var temp = readPreference.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
radioButton1.Checked = bool.TryParse(temp[0], out tempBool);
radioButton2.Checked = bool.TryParse(temp[1], out tempBool);
```

but no matter the value of temp[0] and temp[1], `RadioButton1.Checked` will always become false and `RadioButton2.Checked` will always become true.

Here are the 2 possible cases, the first one:

```
temp[0] = false;
temps[1] = true;
radioButton1.Checked = temp[0] //it's supposed to become false but it stays true
radioButton2.Checked = temp[1] //it becomes true
```

and so `radioButton1.Checked` becomes false and `radioButton2.Checked` stays true.

the second one:

```
temp[0] = true;
temps[1] = false;
radioButton1.Checked = temp[0] //it becomes true
radioButton2.Checked = temp[1] //it becomes false
```

but then, `radioButton1.Checked` becomes false and `radioButton2.Checked` becomes true

How is this possible and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the following code -

```
radioButton1.Checked = bool.TryParse(temp[0], out tempBool);
radioButton2.Checked = bool.TryParse(temp[1], out tempBool);
```

`bool.TryParse` will always return true if it able to successfully parse the first parameter into bool value.  What you need to do is.

```
bool tempBool_1 = false, tempBool_2 = false;
if(bool.TryParse(temp[0], out tempBool_1))
{
      radioButton1.Checked = tempBool_1;
}
else
{
    // handle parsing error.
}
if(bool.TryParse(temp[0], out tempBool_2))
{
      radioButton2.Checked = bool.TryParse(temp[1], out tempBool_2);
}
else
{
    // handle parsing error.
}
```

Comment: I have just replaced `radioButton1.Checked = bool.TryParse(temp[0], out tempBool);` by `radioButton1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(temp[0]);` and it works

Comment: Yes that should also work. But if for some reason, you expect the values in the registry could get corrupted then `Convert.ToBoolean()` will throw exception if it fails to parse the value.

Comment: If I catch the exception, values are set to default so there won't be any problem.